# Get Count of each record With Subquery using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**My Db design is :**

```
 Tbl_id       booked_by   date
    1          W          2014-02-01
    2          P          2014-02-01
    3          P          2014-02-01
    4          P          2014-02-01
    5          W          2014-02-04
    6          W          2014-02-04
    7          P          2014-02-04
```

I want to display counting of W , P  Where given Date and Grouped by Date and  with Using php mysql ..

like

**I NEED OUTPUT LIKE THIS:**

```
Tbl_id  W    P   date
   1    1    3  2014-02-01
   2    2    1  2014-02-04
```

I need Mysql Query to get output given in above..

Comment: Where do the values in the first column of the result set come from? And where does '2014-02-11' come from?

Comment: BTW, this question was so radically altered from the original that I think it constitutes a new question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just the result without slno below query will work fine

```
SELECT 
SUM(No_People) as No_People, 
SUM(Breakfast) as Breakfast,
Sum(Lunch) as Lunch,
`date` as date
FROM table_Name
GROUP BY `date`
```

Output:

```
No_people  Breakfast Lunch   date
    84       112      160    2014-02-11
    116      96       118    2014-02-04
```

But if you also want serial no. to be displayed then below query will work

```
SELECT 
@slno := @slno + 1 as slno
SUM(No_People) as No_People, 
SUM(Breakfast) as Breakfast,
Sum(Lunch) as Lunch,
`date` as date
FROM table_Name, (select @slno := 0 ) sln
GROUP BY `date`
```

Output:

```
slno  No_people  Breakfast Lunch   date
   1          84    112      160    2014-02-11
   2         116    96       118    2014-02-04
```

Comment: Hai , if i want to get sum of no_people for breakfast , lunch what query i should use. Like SUM(no_people) where food_time=breakfast .. using sub query i should perform this

Answer (score 1):

You need the SUM() function, not the COUNT().

```
SELECT
SUM(No_people),
SUM(Breakfast),
SUM(Lunch),
`date`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY `date`
```

I did not include the Tbl_id, because every column you select must be used with an aggregate function or be included in the `group by` clause. Otherwise it's undetermined which row of the group is selected. Selecting it anyway only works in MySQL, but it does not adhere to the SQL standard. If you want some kind of row number instead either Ravinder's approach or create one on application level (which certainly is easier).

UPDATE:

```
SELECT
SUM(booked_by = 'W') AS W,
SUM(booked_by = 'P') AS P,
`date`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY `date`
```

You still need the SUM() function. `booked_by = 'whatever'` evaluates to true (1) or false (0).

Comment: i think you got a down vote bcoz u have to add the tbl_Id and use alias

Comment: @Nouphal.M I got no downvote as far as I can see. Plus I added an explanation why I didn't include the tbl_id. Why I didn't use aliases? It's good enough to give the right answer, although the OP didn't show a single research effort. That's just good will of me. I do not have to give him the most perfect answer where he doesn't have to write a single character and just has to copy&paste. I'm here to give answers and help, not to gain reputation at all costs.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please use the check left to an answer to accept it as solved and working. Learn more about how this site works in a quick tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SUM` aggregate function for summation and a temp row number for `Tbl_id`.

```
select
 @rwnm:=@rwnm+1 as Tbl_id,
 sum(No_people) as No_people,
 sum(Breakfast) as Breakfast,
 sum(Lunch) as Lunch,
 date 
from my_table, ( select @rwnm := 0 ) rownums
group by date
```

Comment: Your posting update is 100% different to the original. You should have opened a new query.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following data set...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id       INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,booked_by   CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'W','2014-02-01'),
(2,'P','2014-02-01'),
(3,'P','2014-02-01'),
(4,'P','2014-02-01'),
(5,'W','2014-02-04'),
(6,'W','2014-02-04'),
(7,'P','2014-02-04');
```

Here's a pivot query...

```
SELECT date
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN booked_by = 'W' THEN 'foo' END) W
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN booked_by = 'P' THEN 'foo' END) P 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY date;
+------------+---+---+
| date       | W | P |
+------------+---+---+
| 2014-02-01 | 1 | 3 |
| 2014-02-04 | 2 | 1 |
+------------+---+---+
```

In my opinion, a better idea (more flexible, more scalable) is simply to return a GROUPED (and, therefore, ordered) result set and handle the rest at in the presentation layer (e.g. a simple PHP loop)...

```
SELECT date,booked_by,COUNT(*) ttl FROM my_table GROUP BY date,booked_by;
+------------+-----------+-----+
| date       | booked_by | ttl |
+------------+-----------+-----+
| 2014-02-01 | P         |   3 |
| 2014-02-01 | W         |   1 |
| 2014-02-04 | P         |   1 |
| 2014-02-04 | W         |   2 |
+------------+-----------+-----+
```